# User registration on Swift using Postman

Tags: swift, swiftui, postman

I tried to look up information about this but couldn't find much. I've previously used Firebase for user registration, but now I have to do a project using Postman. Are there any resources where I can learn to POST to Postman using Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you mean to say is - You have previously worked with Swift and Firebase but not with Swift and REST APIs (Not Postman). Postman is only a client for making HTTP requests to REST, SOAP, or Graph API services. Unlike Firebase ( a Backend as a service ), working with APIs and HTTP Requests (POST, GET, etc) in your application requires a bit more effort.

What you need to research is how to work with REST APIs in Swift.
Here are some resources that might be helpful:

[How to Make Your First API call in Swift](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-first-api-call-in-swift/)

[How to Make HTTP Request with URLSession in Swift](https://medium.com/dev-genius/how-to-make-http-requests-with-urlsession-in-swift-4dced0287d40)

[Creating A REST API Manager in Swift](https://petrosdemetrakopoulos.medium.com/creating-a-rest-api-manager-in-swift-4cd610699bed)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this. I've done JSON parsing and I've used Alamofire as well as SwiftyJSON, so hopefully I'll have an easier time understanding how to create a REST API Manager

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straight forward, have fun exploring  @NicoCobelo